# Actor cannot receive message sent to `mailbox.Sender ()`?

Tags: f#, akka.net, akka.fsharp

I created the following test code - .Net core 2.1 console application. It prints the following message only

> TestActor received message MyTask ("Test1","Test1") from [akka://MySystem/user/Scheduler#1426101451]

But the message `Ok 0` cannot be received by the actor `scheduler`?

```
open System
open Akka.FSharp
open Akka

type MyTask = MyTask of item1: string * item2: string 

let system = System.create "MySystem" <| Configuration.load ()

let scheduler (actors: Actor.IActorRef) (mailbox: Actor<Result<int, string>>) =
    let rec loop (list: int list list) = actor {
        let! m = mailbox.Receive ()
        let sender = mailbox.Sender ()
        let akkaName = mailbox.Self.Path.Name
        printfn "%s received message %A from %A" akkaName m sender
        return! loop []
    }
    actors <! MyTask("Test1", "Test1")
    loop []

let processor (mailbox: Actor<MyTask>) =
    let rec loop () = actor {
        let! m = mailbox.Receive ()
        let sender = mailbox.Sender ()
        let akkaName = mailbox.Self.Path.Name
        printfn "%s received message %A from %A" akkaName m sender
        sender <! Ok 0 // scheduler cannot receive this message?
        return! loop ()
    }
    loop ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let actor = spawn system "TestActor" processor
    spawn system "Scheduler" (scheduler actor) |> ignore
    system.WhenTerminated.Wait()
    0
```

---

### Update:

It works after I changed the parameter from `(mailbox: Actor<Result<int, string>>)` to `(mailbox: Actor<_>)`?

Answer (score 1):

The `scheduler` isn't the sender of the `MyTask` message to which the `processor` is replying, because you are doing the tell (`<!`) from outside the actor computation.  That means it's basically being sent with no sender.  You can use the `Tell` method on `IActorRef` to send with an explicit sender, since you want to send it from outside the context of your actor computation:

`actors.Tell(MyTask("Test1", "Test1"), mailbox.Self)`

**EDIT**

Another issue is that the `mailbox` parameter to the `scheduler` is typed as `Actor<Result<int, string>>`, but since `Ok 0` will be inferred as `Result<int,obj>` in your context, it won't match the actor type signature, and the message will be ignored.  When defining an actor with a specific message type, any messages of a different type will be ignored.

Comment: I tried it with `mailbox.Self` but it still not working. However, it works after I changed the parameter from `(mailbox: Actor<Result<int, string>>) ` to `(mailbox: Actor<_>) `?

Comment: Oh, right.  Your actor type was also restricting the messages that could be received by that actor.  `Ok 0` was probably inferred as `Result<int,'a>` or `Result<int,obj>`, and therefore not being received even with the correct sender.  If you changed the code sending the message to explicitly type `Ok 0` as `Result<int, string>`, your original actor type definition would probably work.

Comment: BTW, I found there is no need to use `actors.Tell(MyTask("Test1", "Test1"), mailbox.Self)`. `sender <! Ok 0` works fine. My real code is still not working even after I change the type parameter to `Actor<_>`. Still investigating.